# Stuff terminal command error into Robot Framework report

Tags: robotframework

Still new to Robot Framework - Quick Question:
The command that is executed via Robot Framework generates an error dump on the terminal.  I would like to pick up the error and stuff it into the log.html#s1-t1 in the Robot Framework report.

Here is my Python Code:

```
from test.testing import testcase
from testers import *

def run_testcase():
        main(module=testcase, action='simulate')
```

Here is my Robot Framework code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                testing_testcase.py


*** Test Cases ***
Testing the testcase - (TC462)
  Run testcase
```

All I want is some help on how to capture the error generated by the command in the terminal and stuff it into the Robot Framework report.

These are the dumps, I'd like to capture in the report.  This command was run manually:

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:~ john.doe$ ~/models/.venv/bin/python /Users/john.doe/models/cores/mumimo/pycores/mumimo/testing_testcase.py simulate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/cores/mumimo/pycores/mumimo/testing_testcase.py", line 138, in <module>
    main3()
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/src/mymytask/mymytask.py", line 529, in main3
    env = environment()
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/.venv/src/mytask/mytask/_block.py", line 125, in __call__
    self.srcline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/.venv/src/mytask/mytask/_block.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.subs = _flatten(func(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/src/mymytask/mymytask.py", line 527, in environment
    tb = args.testbench(ports, params)
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/.venv/src/mytask/mytask/_block.py", line 125, in __call__
    self.srcline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/john.doe/models/.venv/src/mytask/mytask/_block.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.subs = _flatten(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by an error generated on the terminal you mean the keyword fails and you see it in the conosle during the run, then use the keyword [Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) - it returns 2 variables, the status of the embedded keyword, and either its output on success, or the error/exception on failure (your desired case).

So the body of your test case would be:

```
Testing the testcase - (TC462)
    ${rc}  ${msg}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Run testcase
    Run Keyword If    '${rc}' == 'FAIL'    Log    The error is: ${msg}
               ...    ELSE    Log the keyword did not fail, its output is: ${msg}

    Run Keyword If    '${rc}' == 'FAIL'    Fail    Failing the case, the keyword failed
```

---

Looking at the updated question, it *seems* to me you want to log not only the particular exception - which would happen with the above code, but also the full stack trace.

If that is so, there is a change in the python code that should be done - you have to get and return it as part of the function.

There is a python module just for that - `traceback`, and more specifically its [format_exec](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc). Here's a sample how it could be done, shape it a bit according to your needs:

```
import traceback
from test.testing import testcase
from testers import *

def run_testcase():
    try:
        main(module=testcase, action='simulate')
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        raise Exception(tb)
```

So *any* exception is caught (that's a wide net, you might want to change it to something more specific), the stack trace is stored as a string in `tb`, and then reraised - so RF catches it, marks the keyword as failed, and the code in the first part logs it.

Comment: Thanks @Todor - Very helpful.  However, the console error during run is multiple lines and the code you provided still does not log the entire error messages dumped on the console.  Furthermore, now this test gets marked as PASS even though it should be marked as FAIL.

Comment: To fail the case when the keyword fails, you have to call it explicitly, based on the `${rc}` value. I'll add it to the answer; and you add to the question what are you seeing in the console, and what do you want to turn up in the log.

Comment: I added what I want to turn up in the log. Thanks for the help BTW.

Comment: @pythonian check the update in the answer, I think we are getting there :)

Comment: Great. @Todor made the change to the python script - Anything I should do on the RF side?

Comment: That should be it

Comment: Tried it, but it only picks up the first line of the error stack.  Shall I add a limit?